# Queuing and inventory models in R

Tags: r, inventory

I am planning of offering a course in Operations Research and Modelling in R to undergraduate students of agricultural economics. Is there a package in R that can help in solving these problems?

Comment: Which problems exactly? I think this question is so vauge and general that it is unlikely to elicit a helpful response.

Comment: This site is dedicated to programming questions, you're unlikely to get a good answer here. There is a multitude of packages that allow all kind of models, and frankly, we start by letting them program their own calculations. That's the only way they understand what's going on behind the equations in the theoretical course.

Answer (score 2):

For basic Markovian queueing systems you can try the package "queueing".

Answer (score 1):

There's a great place to find [up-to-date, annotated collections of R packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/)

There's a page dedicated to [Optimization and Mathematical Programming](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)

Looks like this should fit your needs well.